# How do undo add/delete in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Accidentally some renames became delete/add.
How can I repair this in Mercurial?

I also added some files which should be copied (hg copy) from other locations in the repo)

Comment: Renames often look like adds and deletes, especially in other tools. You may not have an issue to solve.

Comment: What if I want to merge later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg rollback`: one-level undo. Will undo the last pull or commit (can be dangerous)

`hg backout`: create a new commit that is the inverse of a given commit. Net effect is an undo, but the change remains in your history.

`hg strip`: remove (destroy) changes from history. Removing a changeset also removes all of its children, so it can only be used to truncate history, not remove a slice.

[Ref](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html)